# swapping images on hover with preload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a logo listing which I would like to enhance with an hover effect. (logo in color <-> logo in black and white)

I have the following markup:

```js
  var sourceToggle = function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var newSource = $this.data('hover');
      $this.data('hover', $this.attr('src'));
      $this.attr('src', newSource);
  }

  $(function() {
      $('img[data-hover]').each(function() { 
          new Image().src = $(this).data('hover'); 
      }).hover(sourceToggle, sourceToggle);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="url">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/" data-hover="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/sports/1/">
</a>
```

This code is working fine so far, but I would like to know if it is good code, or if I could make it shorter.

Also I would like to know if it is possible to preload the hover image, because sometimes it is not loaded fast enough and I see a flickering.

Comment: Even if you preload them by having invisible `<img>` elements, you are still going to end up with flickering sometimes. I would probably just have two elements and then make one or the other visible depending on the hover state.

Comment: You already preload the images with script using `new Image().src = $(this).data('hover');`, you can inspect in browser. Could be you just have plenty of images on one page.

Comment: @skobaljic thanks for your comment, haven't seen it, I will check where the flickering comes from, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove 'hover' Javascript part and let CSS do its job. Run JS just to prepare the field and than let the browser relax.

Here is a sample code (also a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkukvk4v/)):

```js
  $(function () {
      $('img[data-hover]').each(function () {
          var thisImage = $(this);
          var hoverSrc = thisImage.data('hover');
          var hoverImage = $('<img class="bw_image" src="' + hoverSrc + '" />');
          thisImage.after(hoverImage);
      })
  });
```

```css
.hovering {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.hovering img {
    display: block;
}
.bw_image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: .01;
    transition: opacity ease-in-out .2s;
}
.bw_image:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="hovering" href="url">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/" data-hover="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/sports/1/" />
</a> 
<a class="hovering" href="url">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2/" data-hover="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/sports/2/" />
</a>
<a class="hovering" href="url">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/3/" data-hover="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/sports/3/" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to, I would replace the whole thing with a pure CSS hover effect and background image.

Your hover image can be "preloaded" if you make a sprite out of it (one image which is nudged over when hovered), so for example:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  background: url('http://i61.tinypic.com/2cxbyaq.png') no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

a:hover {
  background-position: -200px 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="url"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a responsive page, so I need a real image so i resizes itself on smaller screens.

Comment: @emjay You can do that with CSS backgrounds too.

Comment: @MrLister Okay, then please tell me how :) I have svg images an I need the image dimensions and aspect ratio for scaling it down. With the background image solution i need to use fix width and height for the div, and so I think it will not work.